# Factorizing polynomials in $\mathbf{Z}[[x]]$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f(x)\in\mathbf{Z}[x]$ be a non-constant, irreducible polynomial, and let $\alpha \in\mathbf{C}$ be a root of $f(x)$. Denote by $\varphi_\alpha:\mathbf{Z}[x]\rightarrow\mathbf{C}$ the ring homomorphism sending $x$ to $\alpha$. Let now $\nu$ be a $p$-adic place of the number field $K=\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $\alpha$ has strictly positive valuation with respect to $\nu$, i.e. such that $\alpha$ belongs to the maximal ideal of the integers of $K$ defined by $\nu$.
There are only a finite number of such places $\nu$, they are precisely those occurring with positive exponent in the prime factorization of the principal fractional ideal of $K$ generated by $\alpha$.

Then $\varphi_\alpha$ can be extended uniquely to a continuous map
$$\varphi_{\alpha,\nu}:\mathbf{Z}[[x]]\rightarrow K_\nu,$$
where $K_\nu$ denotes the completion of $K$ at the place $\nu$ (the topology considered here on $\mathbf{Z}[[x]]$ is the $x$--adic one). Let
$f_\nu(x)\in\mathbf{Z}[[x]]$ be a power series generating the kernel of $\varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ (such ideal should indeed be principal, right?).

Is it true that the $f_\nu(x)$ can be chosen so that
$$f(x)=\prod_{\nu}f_\nu(x),$$
where $\nu$ ranges through the places of $K$ considered above?

EDIT: As suggested below, it would be more correct to ask that $f(x)$ be equal to the product $\prod_{\nu}f_\nu(x)$ only up to units, and for any choices of the $f_\nu(x)$.

Comment: Maybe you could define $\varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ on $\mathbf{Z}_p[[X]]$ instead ? Then you could try to use the Weierstrass preparation theorem. I don't know though if $\ker \varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ is principal in your setting.

Comment: The ideal $\ker \varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ is indeed principal. The proof is as follows : $\mathbf{Z}[[X]]$ is a Noetherian unique factorization domain, so every prime ideal of height $1$ is principal. But $\mathbf{Z}[[X]]$ has Krull dimension $2$ and the image of $\varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ is not a field, so $\ker \varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ is principal.

Comment: Nice, what are your feelings about the question then? Thanks.

Comment: @Tommaso : my feeling is that the equality you mention seems plausible. What you're asking seems to be a generalization of the isomorphism $\mathbf{Z}[[X]]/(X-p) \cong \mathbf{Z}_p$, but I don't see the proof in general...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to the question is yes. Here is the idea of a proof.

Let us assume that $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$. I hope this is not too restrictive for you (hopefully, someone can extend the argument).

Put $(\alpha) = \mathfrak{p}_1^{a_1} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_t^{a_t}$ where the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are distinct maximal ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\nu_i$ be the place of $K$ associated to $\mathfrak{p}_i$. Let $K_i$ be the completion of $K$ with respect to $\mathfrak{p}_i$, and let $\mathcal{O}_i$ be the ring of integers of $K_i$. We have isomorphisms

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{Z}[[X]]/(f) \cong \varprojlim_{n \geq 1} \mathbf{Z}[X]/(X^n,f) \cong  \varprojlim_{n \geq 1} \mathcal{O}_K/(\alpha^n)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\cong \varprojlim_{n \geq 1} \prod_{i=1}^t \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_i^{a_i n} \cong \prod_{i=1}^t \mathcal{O}_{i}.
\end{equation*}
Now, convince yourself that the composition is just $(\varphi_{\alpha,\nu_1},\ldots,\varphi_{\alpha,\nu_t})$, using your notations (this is because $X$ is sent to $\alpha$).

Recall that $\mathbf{Z}[[X]]$ is a UFD. We already know (see my comment to the question) that $\ker(\varphi_{\alpha,\nu_i}) = (f_i)$ with $f_i \in \mathbf{Z}[[X]]$ irreducible. The ideals $(f_i)$ are pairwise distinct (they are the preimages of distinct ideals of $\prod_{i=1}^t \mathcal{O}_{\nu_i}$). So we get $(f)=\cap_{i=1}^t (f_i)=(f_1 \cdots f_t)$.

Comment: This is precisely the way I was trying to prove the statement yesterday, as I was talking to a friend. In the chain of isomorphisms you describe above, probably it is not so essential that $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]=\mathcal{O}_K$, I will check if the same argument works when $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ is not even finite over $\mathbf{Z}$, i.e. when $\alpha$ is not an algebraic integer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f$ is monic with constant term $\pm1$ (e.g. $f(x)=x-1$). Then there are no places $\nu$ as in the question, because every root is an algebraic unit. Therefore the displayed product is $1$.

Comment: Good point. However in this special case f(x) is a unit in $\mathbf{Z}[[x]]$ and, up to units, the empty product, being equal to 1, is also a unit.

Comment: Probably it would then be more correct to ask to the equality above expressing the factorization to hold up to units.

Comment: Tommaso: $f(x)=2x-2$ seems to have the same problem?

Comment: The problem with 2x-2 is it is not irreducible (you can factor a 2).

Answer (score 3):

Edited due to mistakes pointed out in the comments:

I think the answer to the problem might be yes.  Here are some preliminary thoughts.

First, you know $f_{\nu}(x)$ divides $f(x)$, since $f(x)$ is always in the kernel, the kernel is principal, and $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ is a UFD.

Second, you know $f_{\nu}(x)$ is irreducible, else you don't map into a domain.

Third, I think you can probably prove that these polynomials (the $f_{\nu}(x)$) are distinct.  If so continue:

Fourth, this all says that $\prod_{\nu}f_{\nu}(x)$ divides $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.  So, to get the result you just have to prove that the constant coefficients agree up to a unit (i.e. up to $\pm 1$).  This is equivalent to showing that the constant coefficient of $f_{\nu}(x)$ is $p^{f_{P}\nu_{P}(\alpha)}$ where $P$ is the prime (above $p$) associated to $\nu$ and $f_{P}$ is the inertial degree of $P$ in the ring of integers over $K$.  (Sorry for the double use of $f$--for the polynomial and for the inertial degree.)

Comment: Are you sure there are no such places $\nu$? If I haven't made a mistake, I think that 2 splits into $\mathfrak{p}\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ and that we can label the roots $\alpha$ and $\tilde{\alpha}$ such that $v_\mathfrak{p}(\alpha)$=$v_{\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}}(\tilde{\alpha})=1$ and $v_\mathfrak{p}(\tilde{\alpha})=v_{\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}}(\alpha)=-1$.

Comment: I think Kevin is right. Notice more generally if the root $\alpha$ of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ has norm equal to one (i.e. leading term = constant term), then for every p-adic place $\nu$ of $K=Q(\alpha)$ for which $\alpha$ is not an integer there must be another p-adic place (same p!) $\nu'$ so that $\alpha$ belongs to the maximal ideal of the valuation ring of $\nu'$. This implies that if there is no place $\nu$ for which $\alpha$ belongs to the maximal ideal defined by $\nu$, then $\alpha$ is a unit and so is $f(x)$.

Comment: I do not understand your counterexamples. I think that in both cases, once you fix a root of your polynomial, you have only one place $\nu$ with the property above. Which, if my question has a positive answer, would mean that $f(x)$ stays irreducible in the power series ring. Which is the case in both your examples!

Comment: I changed my answer.  Hopefully I understood the question enough to write something coherent.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to fix the prime $p$, and I assume you want $f$ to be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. If you don't fix $p$, then $x-6$ is a counter-example (there are two valuations for which $v(6)>0$, but $x-6 \neq (x-6)^2$, even up to units.) If $f$ is not the minimimal polynomial then $(x-2)(x-4)$ is a counterexample.

Subject to these caveats, you are right.

I find it really confusing to multiply over all places as you are doing. What I would rather do is the following: Fix a normal extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which $f$ splits. Let $\alpha_1$, ..., $\alpha_N$ be the roots of $f$ in $L$. Factor $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as $g_1 g_2 \cdots g_k$ and group the $\alpha_i$ together if they are roots of the same $g_j$. Fix an extension $v$ of the $p$-adic valuation to $L$. Then there are $k$ different  $p$-adic valuations of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. They each arise as follows: For each $g_i$, choose a root $\alpha_i$ and let $\phi_i : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \to L$ be the map induced by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha_i$. Then your valuation is $v \circ \phi_i$.

Suppose that $v(\alpha_i)>0$ for the roots of $g_1$, $g_2$, ..., $g_s$ and $v(\alpha_i) \leq 0$ for $g_{s+1}$, \cdots, $g_r$. So you are interested in the first $s$ valuations.

Here are the lemmas you need; I'll leave them as exercises. I'm pretty sure they work.

**Lemma 1:** For $i>s$, the polynomial $g_i$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$

**Lemma 2:** For $i \leq s$, the polynomial $g_i$ can be written as $h_i u_i$ where $u_i$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ and $h_i \in \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.

**Lemma 3:** The kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[[x]] \mapsto L_v$, where $x$ goes to a root of $g_i$, is generated by $h_i$.

Proof of Lemma 3: If the map were from $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$, then the kernel would be generated by $g_i$. Since $h_i = g_i u_i^{-1}$, we see that $h_i$ is in the kernel. If $q$ is in the kernel, then $q=g_i v = h_i u_i v$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$. Since $h_i$ and $q$ are both in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, we see that the coefficients of $u_i v$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$, so they are in $\mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $q$ is a multiple of $h_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.

We take $h_i$ as your representative of the kernel. Then $f$ is $\prod h_i$ times a unit $u$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$. But $f$ and $\prod h_i$ are both in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, so $u$ and $u^{-1}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ and we deduce that $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, as desired.

---

Remark: Lemma 2 should be thought of as an analogue of the [Weierstrass preparation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem), although it is not the standard $p$-adic analogue. To see this, note that the (formal) Weierstrass preparation theorem is

If $g$ is a power series in $x$ and $y$ then $g=uh$ where $u$ is a unit of $k[[x,y]]$ and $h$ is in $k[[y]][x]$.

The standard $p$-adic analogue is: If $g \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ then $g=uh$ with $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ and $h$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Lemma 2 goes in the "other" direction: If $g \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ then $g=uh$ with $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_p[[x]]$ and $h$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.

Comment: David,

I don't think $x-6$ is a counter-example (I tried working that example out myself).  The issue is that x-6 factors in the power series ring over the integers.  If you identify x with 6, then as a 2-adic integer x looks like $0*1+1*2+1*2^{2}+0*2^{3}+\cdots$.  Thus, $x^{n}=0*1+0*2+\cdots + 0*2^{n-1}+1*2^{n}+\cdots$ has its first nonzero term as a coefficient of $2^{n}$.  In particular, we can form a power series $2+x+x^3+x^5+x^6+...$ which maps to zero in $\mathbb{Q}_{2}$ under the identification $x=6$.  (We choose powers of $x$ so that we can use $2$ to carry infinitely.)

Comment: I don't have time to think about this right now, but you raise a good point. Also, I wrote above that $\mathbb{Z}_p \cap \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}$ but of course that isn't true. So it looks like what I have shown is the required statement with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Z}_p \cap \mathbb{Q}$. I think there is something valuable here though; please feel free to improve this.

Comment: I think so too.  You might be able to patch it up by inverting the primes in the constant coefficient different from the prime you are considering, which one *should* intuitively be able to do using elements in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.  But it gets complicated, because the image of $\varphi_{\alpha,\nu}$ can be weird.  (Try $\alpha=3+3\sqrt{2}$.)

Comment: @ David : Letting $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbb{Z}_p \cap \mathbb{Q}$, it seems that you prove that $f = (\prod h_i) \cdot u$ for some $u \in \mathbf{Z}[[x]]$. The constant term of $h_i$ is necessarily a power of $p$ (quotient everything by $x$). So $u(0)$ is the prime-to-$p$-part of $f(0)$. It seems that doing this for all $p$ gives the result, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, in the comment above I meant : $u \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[[X]]^{\times} \cap \mathbb{Z}[[X]]$.

Comment: @David. I will read more carefully your lemmas as soon as I have the chance. Just a comment, $x^2-6$ does indeed factor into the product of two power series $f_2$ and $f_3$, where $f_i$ has constant term equal to $i$ (use the fact that $(2,3)$ are relatively prime and inductively construct the factorization). One has that the power series $f_i$ is "satisfied" by $\sqrt{6}$ in $\mathbf{Q}_i$.